# How to make this connection?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have 2 servers: server1 and server2. I can't use server1's 8080 port directly only throughout server2
Now I do port-forwarding in such way:

> ssh -4 -L 8080:server1:8080 user@server2

and I could connect to the first server by this address:

> localhost:8080

But I want to connect by this address:

> server1:8080

How can I do this?

Comment: How are the two networks connected where the servers are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic port forwarding and use that as you would use a socks server

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:1080 user@server2
```

Then for instance:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:1080 server1:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect your outgoing traffic to server1:8080 to localhost:8080 using iptables `DNAT` rule as follows:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d server1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```